# Remove the link tag if it contains a particular string - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to strip all the  tags containing a specific string,
How can I achieve this in javascript?

this is the string

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://REMOVEME">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ccc">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://abc/REMOVEME">
<div>yes</div>
```

and this the result

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ccc">
<div>yes</div>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery ?

Comment: no, but what if I do that?

Comment: Use `document.querySelectAll()` to find all the `link` tags. Loop over them, and if the `href` attribute contains the string you're looking for, remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such tasks are better [not done with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839).

Instead use the DOM interface available to JavaScript, for instance with this ES6 function:

```js
function removeLinks(html, match) {
    var container = document.createElement('span');
    container.innerHTML = html;
    Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('link[href*=' + CSS.escape(match) + ']'))
        .forEach( link => link.parentNode.removeChild(link) );
    return container.innerHTML;
}

// Sample input
var html = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://REMOVEME">' +
           '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ccc">' +
           '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://abc/REMOVEME">' + 
           '<div>yes</div>';

// Remove links that match REMOVEME
html = removeLinks(html, 'REMOVEME');

// Output result
console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
htmlString.replace(/<link[^>]*href="[^>]*REMOVEME[^>]*"[^>]*>/gi,'')
```